# $.each with Ajax and Variable Modification

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, closures

Why is whereString returning "where " and not "where "+some data. I know this has todo with closures and scoping but I'm not sure how to resolve it.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Here's the code:

```
    function SomeFunction() {
        var whereString = "where ";
        var seperator = " ";

        $.when.apply($(".SomeClass").each(function () {

             var promise = SomeAjaxCall().done(function (data) {
                whereString += seperator + data.d

             });
             seperator = "and "

       }).then(function() { 

         alert("Finished");
         alert(whereString); // Alerts "where " and not "Where "+data.d

      })
   };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note, `.apply()` expects `this` context to be set as first parameter , array as second parameter ; `.each()` does not return an array , also `.each()` appear to be missing closing parenthesis `)` at `js` at Question  .

Try substituting `.map()` for `.each()` with `.get()` chained to `.map()` to return an array of jQuery promise objects, setting `context` : `this` of `$.when.apply` to `$` . Also , include `return promise` within `.map()` to return jQuery promise object to `.then()` .

```
function SomeFunction() {
  var whereString = "where ";
  var seperator = " ";
  // set `this` to `jQuery` alias `$`
  $.when.apply($, $(".SomeClass").map(function(i, el) {
    // do ajax stuff
    var promise = SomeAjaxCall().done(function (data) {
                    whereString += seperator + data.d
                  });
    seperator = "and ";
    // return jQuery promise object
    return promise
  // include closing parenthesis to `.map()` , use `.get()` to return
  // array of jQuery promise objects
  }).get()).then(function() {

    alert("Finished");
    alert(whereString); 

  })
};
```

---

```js
function SomeFunction() {
  var whereString = "where";
  var seperator = " ";
  // set `this` to `jQuery` alias `$`
  $.when.apply($, $(".SomeClass").map(function(i, el) {
    // do asynchronous stuff
    var promise = $.Deferred().resolve({
      "d": el.textContent
    }).done(function(data) {
      whereString += seperator + data.d

    });
    seperator = " and ";
    // return jQuery promise
    return promise
  // include closing parenthesis to `.map()` , use `.get()` to return
  // array of jQuery promise objects
  }).get()).then(function() {

    console.log("Finished");
    console.log(whereString); 

  })
};

SomeFunction()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="SomeClass">abc</div>
<div class="SomeClass">def</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps alot. I'm new to JS and I'm working through Deferreds and Promises.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the alerts are firing after your 'each' function has been called on all the results of the jquery select.  However, SomeAjaxCall() is asynchronous, so, therefore the 'done' function's haven't been called because the ajax calls aren't done by the time the 'each' functions are done executed, and thus the alerts firing.

Though this is probably not what you want in the end, you can add a timeout of a few seconds before doing your alerts to see that the 'where' does eventually get updated.